# Bottom app bar Navigation icon is not center vertical

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-appbarlayout, bottombar

I'm using **`android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar`** but the navigation icon is coming in left top corner when option menu is added.

without Option its working as expected (center_vertical).

**With option menu**

[image]

**Without Option Menu**

[image]

Can any one tell how to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

In your layout, you can change the **BottomAppBar theme** to this:

```xml
<android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

After trying different ways, setting padding through styles worked.

```
<style name="NavButtonPadding" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:paddingStart">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">10dp</item>
</style>
```

[After Adding styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwysK.png)

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Be sure to also declare the new Material style. Declaring it directly in my XML helped me, as well as adding this.  style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `Theme.MaterialComponents` themes as application parent theme when you use Google Material components:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

instead of :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

in `style.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I have also got the same issue, but found a solution by adding:

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
```

for bottomBar.